# Different answers when using anonymous variable and "normal" variable in Prolog

Tags: prolog, prolog-anonymous-variable

I have the following database:

```
vegetarian(jose).
vegetarian(james).
vegetable(carrot).
vegetable(egg_plant).
likes(jose,X):-vegetable(X).
loves(Who,egg_plant):-vegetarian(Who).
```

When I do the query `vegetarian(_).` I was expecting to get `_ = jose; _ = james.` but I am instead getting `true; true.`

If I instead do `vegetarian(X).`, then I get the expected answer `X = jose; X = james.`
Why this difference?

Comment: Which Prolog are you using?

Comment: Pretty sure this is a feature of the Prolog command line (i.e. "the Prolog toplevel"). As you explicitly have stated that you are not interested in the value of certain variables (by using `_` as name), the toplevel won't bother to print the term denoted by `_`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using SWI-Prolog, you can control this with the flag `toplevel_print_anon`). However, a name consisting of a single underscore (`_`) is special and never prints.

```
$ swipl dd.pl
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 8.3.16)
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software.
Please run ?- license. for legal details.

For online help and background, visit https://www.swi-prolog.org
For built-in help, use ?- help(Topic). or ?- apropos(Word).

?- set_prolog_flag(toplevel_print_anon, true).
true.

?- vegetarian(_X).
_X = jose ;
_X = james.

?- vegetarian(_).
true ;
true.

?- set_prolog_flag(toplevel_print_anon, false).
true.

?- vegetarian(_X).
true ;
true.
```